# Implement greater equal sign in C using only bitwise operations

Tags: c, comparison, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I know that many basic operations like addition or division can also be implemented in C using only bitwise operators. How can I do the same with the greater than or equal sign (>=)?

```
if (x >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Err, yes, I always confuse these...

Comment: `if (~~~((x>>(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-1))&~~~0))`. Enjoy.

Comment: @Lundin If that works post as an answer

Comment: @TheUnfunCat It works but it uses non-bitwise operators. Though it does feel like the question deserves such an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution I can come up with:

```
#include <limits.h>

if ((x & INT_MAX) == x)    // if (x >= 0)
    ...
```

If you don't like the `==` then use XOR to do the equals test:

```
#include <limits.h>

if ((x & INT_MAX) ^ x)    // if (x < 0)
    ...
else                      // else x >= 0
    ...
```

Comment: `if` contains implicit comparison so it's not bitwise operations only in a strict meaning.

Comment: @icepack: I expressed it like this for consistency with the original question - if the OP wants something other than this then he'll need to make that clear.

Comment: I'm not sure why every answer has been down-voted, but then again, it's not a great question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `if (x >= 0)` then this is enough

```
if (~x & INT_MIN)
```

If you mean "greater than or equal" between 2 numbers in general then it's a lot more difference

Answer (score -1):

If all you can use is bitwise operators and even the comparison operators are disabled, it's not possible (actually, almost nothing would be possible). Implicit comparison is always present, even operations such as `if(x some bitwise stuff)` are actually interpreted as an equivalent to `if(x some bitwise stuff) != 0)` in the generated assembly code.